# How to create spreadsheet using service account credentials and makeit publically available in node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

Hi I am facing problem as to how to create spreadsheet using service account credentials ?  I have tried every possible thing but I am not able to find correct way to do it. I just need a guidance.

Comment: Can you share your code for creating spreadsheet and making it public. Whiich step did you failed? Creating the spreadsheet or making it public?

Comment: Here is the snippet of my code. Only problem I am facing is as to how to impersonate my email account in the code in Node.js. Google have given examples of impersonating gmail account for python and java but not for node.js.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D58c5.png